# Error upon starting Squid Proxy Server using the command "sudo squid -z"

Tags: 14.04, server, proxy, squid, squid-deb-proxy

I got this error upon starting Squid Proxy Server using the command `sudo squid -z`:

```
fatal: ipc::mem::segment::create failed to shm_open(/squid-cf__metadata.shm): 13 permission denied
```

How shall I fix it? I'm using version `3.5.26` of Squid, I tried implementing the fix below I found in the web:

> Just add the following line to your `/etc/fstab` file:
> `shm /dev/shm tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0` 
> After that use (as root): `# mount shm`

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, another possible fix on the web is error reading `squid.pid`:

```
squid: ERROR: Could not read pid file /var/run/squid.pid: (13) Permission denied
```

As I look in my directory, I could not find `squid.pid`. How will I get my Squid working?

Answer (score 0):

> fatal: ipc::mem::segment::create failed to shm_open()

This error is related to permission denied of accessing a [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) segments (`man shm_open`). The issue is, that you probably run `squid` process with the wrong user (either before or now).

The solution is to remove `.shm` files from `/dev/shm`:

```
$ sudo rm -v /dev/shm/squid*.shm
```

To run `squid` with the right user (e.g. `proxy`), use `sudo`, make sure your `cache_effective_user` is correct in the config file (`squid.conf`), your cache and log directories are owned by that user.

Check the following Docker container at [`sameersbn/docker-squid`](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-squid) as the working example.